# How to correctly map a python function and then batch the Dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, dataset

I wish to create a pipeline to provide non-standard files to the neural network (for example with extension *.xxx).
Currently I have structured my code as follows:

1) I define a list of paths where to find training files

2) I define an instance of the tf.data.Dataset object containing these paths

3) I map to the Dataset a python function that takes each path and returns the associated numpy array (loaded from the folder on the pc); this array is a matrix with dimensions [256, 256, 192].

4) I define an initializable iterator and then use it during network training.

My doubt lies in the size of the batch I provide to the network. I would like to have batches of size 64 supplied to the network. How could I do?
For example, if I use the function train_data.batch(b_size) with b_size = 1 the result is that when iterated, the iterator gives one element of shape [256, 256, 192]; what if I wanted to feed the neural net with just 64 slices of this array?

This is an extract of my code:

```
    with tf.name_scope('data'):
        train_filenames = tf.constant(list_of_files_train)

        train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_filenames)
        train_data = train_data.map(lambda filename: tf.py_func(
            self._parse_xxx_data, [filename], [tf.float32]))

        train_data.shuffle(buffer_size=len(list_of_files_train))
        train_data.batch(b_size)

        iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_data.output_types, train_data.output_shapes)

        input_data = iterator.get_next()
        train_init = iterator.make_initializer(train_data)

  [...]

  with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(train_init)
      _ = sess.run([self.train_op])
```

Thanks in advance

### ----------

**I posted a solution to my problem in the comments below. I would still be happy to receive any comment or suggestion on possible improvements. Thank you ;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time but I'll post a possible solution to batch the dataset with custom shape in TensorFlow, in case someone may need it.

The module `tf.data` offers the method `unbatch()` to unwrap the content of each dataset element. One can first unbatch and than batch again the dataset object in the desired way. Oftentimes, a good idea may also be shuffling the unbatched dataset before batching it again (so that we have random slices from random elements in each batch):

```
with tf.name_scope('data'):
    train_filenames = tf.constant(list_of_files_train)

    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_filenames)
    train_data = train_data.map(lambda filename: tf.py_func(
        self._parse_xxx_data, [filename], [tf.float32]))

    # un-batch first, then batch the data
    train_data = train_data.apply(tf.data.experimental.unbatch())

    train_data.shuffle(buffer_size=BSIZE)
    train_data.batch(b_size)

    # [...]
```

Answer (score -1):

If I clearly understand you question, you can try to slice the array into the shape you want in your `self._parse_xxx_data` function.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Unfortunately, due to time constraints, it would be better to batch the array after calling this function. In fact, due to many constraints, I have to produce an array of [256, 256, 192] within the self.parse_xxx_data() function.
Specifically, these are 192 images of size 256x256, the production of which is time consuming: so I do not want to take only 64 images because it would be a waste of "production" (since the discarded ones can be useful to train the neural net).

Comment: Maybe you should first put 1 image in 1 file before training because when training a neural network, you have to make sure the images in each batch is randomly sampled from the whole dataset.

Comment: Unfortunately this is also a bad choice in my case, because I need to pre-process the volumes as a whole (i.e. doing random 3D rotation, standardization on the whole volume statistics, etc.) and then slice these 3D volumes at run-time because I want to work on 2D slices with the neural net.
Saving such a huge amount of 2D slices would be definitely a sub-optimal and unpractical choice for me.