# ValueError: Tensor proto is larger than 2GB

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I am currently trying to customize a larger dataset with BERT based on the published code on my own data [Colab-Code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb). Since the data is too big for the input, the following error code occurs during the training:

> ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than
>   2GB.

I already tried to adapt the code to this as there is already a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470991/create-a-tensor-proto-whose-content-is-larger-than-2gb), but it doesn't work in the example.

```
def create_model(is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels,
                 num_labels):
  """Creates a classification model."""

  bert_module = hub.Module(
      BERT_MODEL_HUB,
      trainable=True)
  bert_inputs = dict(
      input_ids=input_ids,
      input_mask=input_mask,
      segment_ids=segment_ids)
  bert_outputs = bert_module(
      inputs=bert_inputs,
      signature="tokens",
      as_dict=True)

  # Use "pooled_output" for classification tasks on an entire sentence.
  # Use "sequence_outputs" for token-level output.
  output_layer = bert_outputs["pooled_output"]

  hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value

  # Create our own layer to tune for politeness data.
  output_weights = tf.get_variable(
      "output_weights", [num_labels, hidden_size],
      initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))

  output_bias = tf.get_variable(
      "output_bias", [num_labels], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

  with tf.variable_scope("loss"):

    # Dropout helps prevent overfitting
    output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)

    logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
    logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
    log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)

    # Convert labels into one-hot encoding
    one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels, dtype=tf.float32)

    predicted_labels = tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(log_probs, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32))
    # If we're predicting, we want predicted labels and the probabiltiies.
    if is_predicting:
      return (predicted_labels, log_probs)

    # If we're train/eval, compute loss between predicted and actual label
    per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)
    return (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs)




# model_fn_builder actually creates our model function
# using the passed parameters for num_labels, learning_rate, etc.
def model_fn_builder(num_labels, learning_rate, num_train_steps,
                     num_warmup_steps):
  """Returns `model_fn` closure for TPUEstimator."""
  def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    """The `model_fn` for TPUEstimator."""

    input_ids = features["input_ids"]
    input_mask = features["input_mask"]
    segment_ids = features["segment_ids"]
    label_ids = features["label_ids"]

    is_predicting = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT)

    # TRAIN and EVAL
    if not is_predicting:

      (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs) = create_model(
        is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids, num_labels)

      train_op = bert.optimization.create_optimizer(
          loss, learning_rate, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu=False)

      # Calculate evaluation metrics. 
      def metric_fn(label_ids, predicted_labels):
        accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(label_ids, predicted_labels)
        f1_score = tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels)
        auc = tf.metrics.auc(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels)
        recall = tf.metrics.recall(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels)
        precision = tf.metrics.precision(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels) 
        true_pos = tf.metrics.true_positives(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels)
        true_neg = tf.metrics.true_negatives(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels)   
        false_pos = tf.metrics.false_positives(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels)  
        false_neg = tf.metrics.false_negatives(
            label_ids,
            predicted_labels)
        return {
            "eval_accuracy": accuracy,
            "f1_score": f1_score,
            "auc": auc,
            "precision": precision,
            "recall": recall,
            "true_positives": true_pos,
            "true_negatives": true_neg,
            "false_positives": false_pos,
            "false_negatives": false_neg
        }

      eval_metrics = metric_fn(label_ids, predicted_labels)

      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
          loss=loss,
          train_op=train_op)
      else:
          return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
            loss=loss,
            eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)
    else:
      (predicted_labels, log_probs) = create_model(
        is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids, num_labels)

      predictions = {
          'probabilities': log_probs,
          'labels': predicted_labels
      }
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

  # Return the actual model function in the closure
  return model_fn
```

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Comment: @gabriele yes still a problem

Answer (score 1):

As you can read here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4291

> There is a hard limit of 2GB for serializing individual tensors because of the 32bit signed size in protobuf.

You should use `tf.Dataset` instead. The most straightforward way to do this is to create a **TFRecord** object. You can find examples on how to do this at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records.

Another approach (but this really depend on how the data is structured) may be defining a `tf.Dataset` containing a list of paths for the training examples. Then you can map a function to each path in the dataset of paths and parse each file in classic python code (you can find an example here: [How to correctly map a python function and then batch the Dataset in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043703/how-to-correctly-map-a-python-function-and-then-batch-the-dataset-in-tensorflow) ).